# Fastest way to transpose a matrix stored in an 1D array in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Given a vector `v` of length `N^2` that holds the entries of a `NxN` matrix `M`, what is the fastest way to compute the transpose of `M` in the same vector representation using NumPy?

I know this can be done by

```
v.reshape(N, N).T.flatten()
```

but is this the fastest way?

I am not interested in the intermediate explicit form of `M`.

Comment: `flatten` accepts `order` as the argument. I guess that if you set it to `'A'`, then you will not need to transpose the matrix

Comment: `reshape` makes a view, `T` does as well.  But `flatten` will make a copy (reshape after a transpose also makes a copy).  Assuming that at least one copy is needed, I don't think you can improve on the speed.

Comment: Why are you looking for "fastest" as opposed to say "most legible"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a test case:

```
In [207]: N=1000
In [208]: X = np.arange(N*N)
```

Your code:

```
In [209]: Y = X.reshape(N,N).T.flatten()
In [210]: timeit Y = X.reshape(N,N).T.flatten()
5.45 ms ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

A suggested alternative:

```
In [211]: Z = X.reshape(N,N).flatten('F')
In [212]: np.allclose(Y,Z)
Out[212]: True
In [213]: timeit Z = X.reshape(N,N).flatten('F')
5.46 ms ± 39.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

No real difference.  `reshape` and `transpose` are views.